# how to customize / override antd styles?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm trying to customize antd ant-row class within my form component so I can change the height between input fields. I have defined a different class name to my form and tried to do modify it in the css file however it's not being modified or applied. Can someone please help?

Form.js

```
 {this.state.active2 && (
          <Form
            style={{
              position: 'relative',
              zindex: '2',
              left: '35%',
              overflow: 'initial',
              width: '300px',
            }}
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            className="login-form"
            layout={formLayout}>

            <Form.Item>
            <Form.Item label="Full name" {...formLayout}>
              {form.getFieldDecorator('username', {
                rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' }],
              })(
                <Input
                  prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />}
                  placeholder="input placeholder" 
                />,
              )}
            </Form.Item>

            </Form.Item>
```

styles.scss

```
 .login-form.ant-row {
    position: relative !important;
    height: 70px !important;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    zoom: 1 !important;
    display: block !important;
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to adjust the margin between every `Form.Item`?

Comment: yes right now they are very far apart from each other i would like to get them closer to each other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to style the `Form.Item` component, for example with **inline-style**:

```js
// The current form item is margin 15px top.
<Form.Item style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}>
  <Input />
</Form.Item>
```

Or the entire `Form` by overriding the css-class, for example with **CSS-in-JS**:

```js
// Apply style to all form
const StyledForm = styled(Form)`
  .ant-form-item {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
`;
```

Demo:

[image: Edit Q-56637063]

Same can be achieved with `.css` file and importing it:

```css
:global .ant-form-item {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Just choose whatever you like, I am sure you can figure it out

Comment: how do i remove the gap between the form items ? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

`antd` provides you with LESS variables you can [override](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#Ant-Design-Less-variables).

Of course, this doesn't satisfy every condition. But if your styles are not being applied, the problem has to do with CSS selector weight, and how specificity is calculated i.e. your selector is not specific enough to override antd styles. You need to change your selectors to have a higher specificity.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: i copied the exact selector from inspect element

Comment: Yes but that element also has parents which are attributing to its over all sytle. You need to traverse the tree to be sure as antd components put put very nested html elements.

Comment: Yes, by traversing through the tree

Comment: you mean in inspect element? I only see .ant-row .ant-form-item

Comment: in your example there is no space between the two classes, try separating them like so `.login-form .ant-row` put a space between .login-form and .ant-row

Comment: These were completely useless edits imo. Contributed absolutely nothing to the answer.... A completely terrible use of your time.